# How to check if there is nothing to move in Outlook VBA?

Tags: vba, outlook

Code as below:

```
Sub olFromSysItems_ItemAdd(ByVal item As Object)

    Dim EventMessage As String
    Dim strErrMessage As String
    Dim objMailFromSys As clsMailFromSys

On Error GoTo Error_Handler

    Set objMailFromSys = New clsMailFromSys
    objMailFromSys.SetMailObject item

    If objMailFromSys.Function1(strErrMessage) = False Then
       GoTo Error_Handler
    End If

    If objMailFromSys.Function2(strErrMessage) = False Then
        GoTo Error_Handler
    End If

    If objMailFromSys.Function3(strErrMessage) = False Then
        GoTo Error_Handler
    End If

    item.Move folderFromSys_Processed
    Set objMailFromSys = Nothing
    Exit Sub

Error_Handler:

    EventMessage = "Error email from " & item.SenderName & "." & Chr(12)
    If Len(Trim(strErrMessage)) = 0 Then
        EventMessage = EventMessage & "olFromSysItems_ItemAdd Error: " & Err.Description & Chr(12)
    Else
        EventMessage = EventMessage & strErrMessage & Chr(12)
    End If
    EventMessage = EventMessage & "Please also check the email folder Error"
    EventMessage = Chr(34) & EventMessage & Chr(34)

    LogEvent EventMessage
    Set objMailFromSys = Nothing
    item.Move folderError

    SendErrorMessageToAdmin "Error Email from VBA", EventMessage, item

End Sub
```

Once in a while it will have error at the following line:

```
item.Move folderError
```

with the following error message:

> The items were copied instead of moved because the original items
>   could not be deleted. The item could not be deleted. It was either moved or already deleted, or access denied.

My question(s):

1. How do I check if there is nothing to move in outlook VBA?
2. How do I check if I cannot move item to a folder in outlook VBA?

Comment: @Jules The parameter that this function accept `(ByVal item As Object)`, can be mail item.

Comment: Can you declare it as mail instead of generic object?  Also you may find the answer if you search using the actual object name and the error message on the internet.  Did a search and found this. https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/kb/924254

Answer (score 0):

If you have not found another approach then bypassing the error could work here.

```
' Use only for a specific purpose
On Error Resume Next
item.Move folderError
' Turn error bypass off once the purpose for it has been served
On Error GoTo 0
```